# Graphic size in slides

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm doing a slide presentation with LaTeX, and some slides show only graphics. I created those graphics using R. But in those slides, the graphic size is too big and a part of the graphic does not appear in the slide, like it's been cropped. Is there any command in LaTeX that can make the graphic smaller in the slide?

Comment: you can set the size of the graphic as an option, e.g.`\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{mygraph}` will scale the graph so that it is half of the current text width (and scale the height by the some amount). check the documentation for the `graphicx` package for this and other options available

Comment: I had the same problem. R Markdown to produce `beamer` presentation, wanted to include `png` images *not* created by `R` within the markdown doc. No control over size. A workable solution is to use the `png` library in R to read the images and plot inside a `R` chunk, giving you control over size via `fig.width` and `fig.height`. [From this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown/15626317#15626317)

Answer (score 6):

The `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package can take a number of optional arguments, such as `scale`, `width`, and `height`. You can use these to get the desired size- a MWE follows

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
 %\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{mypicture}
 \includegraphics[width=2cm]{mypicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you are trying to create `beamer` slides with R markdown. See my comment on the question for a solution.